# New tab with preventDefault and jQuery load

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have a handler of hyperlinks with `preventDefault` method there. I want to open a link in a new tab and load specific content with jQuery `.load()` method. What is the best way to do this?
Here is code of hyperlink handler and the way I load content.

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr("target")=="_blank"){
        // open at new tab and make some actions
    }
    else {
        //some actions
    }
});

$(".loadedContent").click(function(){
   $(".content").load("loadedContent.html");
});
```

Comment: Need to see some code, or the answers will be opinion based

Comment: Added some code now. Enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the link in a new tab, but remember you will not be able to access that page using jQuery. You will have to load a URL where you will have the jQuery `.load()` code. For example:

```
if($(this).attr("target") == "_blank") {
  window.open('url');
}
```

Then in the new tab, you can load the page where you're having the method. Like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div').load('the_new_url.html');
      }); // do remember to add the jquery file to the HTML document. 
    </script>
    <div></div> <!--You'll find the new content in the DIV-->
  </body>
</html>
```

It would be pretty messy!

To use the `.load()` method it is good to be using this method on the very same page, to load the new content and to replace the existing content by the content being fetched. These popups annoy users! As **Rex** mentioned, answers would be opinion based, so my opinion would be use the method on the same page instead of new tab!

If it was me, I would have used the above code to populate the content on the DOM load event. And on each element click, I would have updated the content depending on the element and the event!

Comment: it's ok. I found information about window.open, but how can new window understand what page will it load? I should make a new tab to load certain content.

Comment: It will load the page that you will provide it with in the first parameter as: `window.open('http://www.google.com');`, this will open Google website!